# QTreeWidget icons issue

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I want to display users avatars to `treewidget` items as icons. I get `avatars path` and other users info from the database and store it in `QVector` with the structure.

```
MyDB *employeesAccountsDB = new MyDB();
  connect(employeesAccountsDB, &MyDB::accountInfo, [this](QVector<AccountData> dataVector) {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataVector.size(); i++) {
             QTreeWidgetItem *item = new QTreeWidgetItem(treeWidget);
             item->setSizeHint(0, QSize(40, 40));
             item->setText(0, dataVector[i].avatarPath);
             item->setText(1, dataVector[i].username);
             item->setText(2, dataVector[i].email);
             item->setText(3, dataVector[i].group);
             emit avatarPath(dataVector[i].avatarPath);
        }

        dataVector.clear();
   });
```

`Info` is a GUI class.

```
NetManager *avatarNetManager = new NetManager();
connect(this, &Info::avatarPath, avatarNetManager, &NetManager::getAvatar);
 connect(avatarNetManager, &NetManager::image, [this](QPixmap avatar, int index) {
        QIcon avatarIcon;

        if (!avatar.isNull()) {
            avatarIcon = avatar.scaled(80, 80);
        } else {
            avatarIcon = QPixmap(":/Icon/default_avatar.png").scaled(80, 80);
        }

        qDebug() << index;
        treeWidget->topLevelItem(index)->setIcon(0, avatarIcon);
  });

int index = 0; // initialized as global variable in the `NetManager` constructor
void NetManager::getAvatar(QString path, int index)
{
    networkManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    networkManager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(path)));

    connect(networkManager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, [this](QNetworkReply *avatarNetReply) {
        QPixmap avatarPixmap;
        avatarPixmap.loadFromData(avatarNetReply->readAll());
        emit image(avatarPixmap, index);
        index++;
        avatarNetReply->close();
        avatarNetReply->deleteLater();
        networkManager->deleteLater();
        emit finished();
    });
}
```

For example, first icon is Ok, third icon should be on the second item and second icon should be on third item.

[image: 0_1521551133400_2018-03-20_150423.png]

I need something to maintain the order of the icons.

All works well but the avatars don't relate to the users. Any ideas how to collect and retrieve them to the appropriate user? Thanks.

**Updated:**

INDEX: 2
QPixmap(QSize(1280, 720),depth=32,devicePixelRatio=1,cacheKey=0xee000002d0)
INDEX: 0
QPixmap(QSize(380, 400),depth=32,devicePixelRatio=1,cacheKey=0xf000000190)
INDEX: 1
QPixmap(QSize(277, 400),depth=32,devicePixelRatio=1,cacheKey=0xf200000190)

INDEX: 0
QPixmap(QSize(380, 400),depth=32,devicePixelRatio=1,cacheKey=0xed00000190)
INDEX: 2
QPixmap(QSize(1280, 720),depth=32,devicePixelRatio=1,cacheKey=0xf0000002d0)
INDEX: 1
QPixmap(QSize(277, 400),depth=32,devicePixelRatio=1,cacheKey=0xf200000190)

Indices change every time application launches.

**Code:**

```
      MyDB *employeesAccountsDB = new MyDB();
      connect(employeesAccountsDB, &MyDB::accountInfo, [this](QVector<AccountData> dataVector) {
            for (int i = 0; i < dataVector.size(); i++) {
                 QTreeWidgetItem *item = new QTreeWidgetItem(treeWidget);
                 item->setSizeHint(0, QSize(40, 40));
                 item->setText(0, dataVector[i].avatarPath);
                 item->setText(1, dataVector[i].username);
                 item->setText(2, dataVector[i].email);
                 item->setText(3, dataVector[i].group);
                 emit avatarPath(dataVector[i].avatarPath, i);
            }

            dataVector.clear();
       });


 void NetManager::getAvatar(QString path, int index)
    {
        networkManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
        networkManager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(path)));

        connect(networkManager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, [this, index](QNetworkReply *avatarNetReply) {
            QPixmap avatarPixmap;
            avatarPixmap.loadFromData(avatarNetReply->readAll());
            emit image(avatarPixmap, index);
            avatarNetReply->close();
            avatarNetReply->deleteLater();
            networkManager->deleteLater();
            emit finished();
        });
    }

NetManager *avatarNetManager = new NetManager();
connect(this, &Info::avatarPath, avatarNetManager, &NetManager::getAvatar);
 connect(avatarNetManager, &NetManager::image, [this](QPixmap avatar, int index) {
        QIcon avatarIcon;

        if (!avatar.isNull()) {
            avatarIcon = avatar.scaled(80, 80);
        } else {
            avatarIcon = QPixmap(":/Icon/default_avatar.png").scaled(80, 80);
        }

        qDebug() << index;
        treeWidget->topLevelItem(index)->setIcon(0, avatarIcon);
  });
```

Comment: Can you store a hash key or icon path in your DB? and attach this info in your `AccountData` structure

Comment: @Simon

It's already attached - `dataVector[i].avatarPath` (icon path).

Comment: Add to the ʼavatarPathʼ signal the row index, and use it in the ʼgetAvatarʼ function instead of the global index member.

Comment: @Simon I have removed the global index member and changed to `emit avatarPath(dataVector[i].avatarPath, i);` but the same result.

Comment: Can you please post your update?

Comment: @Simon

The post has been updated.

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem (including any necessary inputs, but preferably not needing any), then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @TobySpeight

I can't post main function or more code. It's very big and complex program.

Comment: The point of a [mcve] is that it's the **shortest** program that demonstrates your problem.  If that's big and complex, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @TobySpeight

The program connects to the database and server, so it will be security risk when I post the data. I will create small project and reproduce the issue there and then post it here.

Comment: Why do you need a database to demonstrate your problem?  The whole point of a [mcve] is that you hard-code the values to make it **reproducible**.  Unless your problem is with the database, in which case you create a minimal database schema and query as the MCVE.  There is absolutely no reason you need a database and a GUI in the same question.  That just makes it hard to find what you're actually struggling with.

Comment: BTW, is there any reason that `NetManager::getAvatar()` accepts an `index` that's never used (the lambda refers to `this->index`, since it doesn't capture anything other than `this`).

Comment: @TobySpeight
The `void NetManager::getAvatar(QString path, int index)` accepts the index as a parameter and it's available in lambda - `[this, index](QNetworkReply *avatarNetReply)` otherwise the image would be default or empty.

https://ddgobkiprc33d.cloudfront.net/f02dbab0-5105-4da1-a700-a72d52dda55a.png

Comment: The code in your question says `[this](QNetworkReply *avatarNetReply)`.  So you haven't even copied it properly.  Please supply a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem, instead of fragments of code and explanation that don't.

Comment: @TobySpeight

You are looking at the old code. Below is the updated code (`Updated:` section), but I already fixed it, so no need to explain more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it by `QString` variable to hold the avatar path and `QStringList` to hold other user info and when image is retrieved from the path I do the following:

```
MyDB *employeesAccountsDB = new MyDB();
connect(employeesAccountsDB, &MyDB::accountInfo, [this](QPixmap avatar, QStringList accountInfo) {
       QIcon avatarIcon;

        if (!avatar.isNull()) {
            avatarIcon = avatar.scaled(80, 80);
        } else {
            avatarIcon = QPixmap(":/Icon/default_avatar.png").scaled(80, 80);
        }

        QTreeWidgetItem *item = new QTreeWidgetItem(treewidget);
        item->setIcon(0, avatarIcon);
        item->setSizeHint(0, QSize(40, 40));

        for (int i = 0; i < accountInfo.size(); i++) {
             item->setText(i, accountInfo.at(i));
        }
 });
```

[image: 0_1521578165291_2018-03-20_223557.png]

All works well.